# how do i add up the total scores of each round

Tags: python

I have created a dice game which displays the scores at the end of each round. I would like to know how to separately add up the scores of both players so it displays the total score of 5 rounds.

This is the code below:

```
import random
import time

def bothDice():
    count=0  
    while count<5:
        count=count+1
        score=0
        print("Round",count)
        print("Player One rolls first dice")
        time.sleep(1)
        dice1=(random.randint(1,6))
        print("you rolled a ",dice1)
        print("Player One rolls second dice")
        time.sleep(1)
        dice2=(random.randint(1,6))
        print("you rolled a ",dice2)

        score=dice1+dice2
        if score%2==0:
            score=score+10

        if dice1==dice2:
            print("You rolled a double- You get an extra roll")
            for x in range (1):
                print("You rolled a:")
                extraDice=(random.randint(1,6))
                print(extraDice)
                extraScore = score+extraDice
                score = extraScore

        else:
            score=score-5

        print("======","Your combined score is ", score,"======")

        score=0
        print("Player Two rolls first dice")
        time.sleep(1)
        dice1=(random.randint(1,6))
        print("you rolled a ",dice1)
        print("Player Two rolls second dice")
        time.sleep(1)
        dice2=(random.randint(1,6))
        print("you rolled a ",dice2)

        score=dice1+dice2
        if score%2==0:
            score=score+10
        if dice1==dice2:
            print("You rolled a double- You get an extra roll")
            for x in range (1):
                print("You rolled a:")
                extraDice=(random.randint(1,6))
                print(extraDice)
                extraScore = score+extraDice
                score = extraScore

        else:
            score=score-5
        print("======","Your combined score is ", score,"======")


def main():
   bothDice()


main()
```

How would I make the scores of each round add together?
Thanks

Comment: Why can't you define two scores? Something like `p1_score` and `p2_score`?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Let's clarify some points: a) `def bothDice():` - there is something obviously wrong with indentation, can you correct subbmitted code ? b) what have you done so far?

Comment: What's not working though? Is the score not being displayed as you wanted?

Comment: the code works perfectly fine on python. i just want to know how to make each players' score at the end of each round add to make a total score

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to re-write your code -- For instance, you can use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop to keep track of rounds. I think use of `dict` or `list` is useful. I added two dictionaries for both players, `result_p1` and `result_p2` that store scores per round. The score can be negative (not sure if intended).

Here is the code below:

```
import random
import time

def bothDice():
    count=0

    # New dicts that store counts
    result_p1 = {}
    result_p2 = {}

    while count<5:
        count=count+1
        score=0
        print("Round",count)
        print("Player One rolls first dice")
        time.sleep(1)
        dice1=(random.randint(1,6))
        print("you rolled a ",dice1)
        print("Player One rolls second dice")
        time.sleep(1)
        dice2=(random.randint(1,6))
        print("you rolled a ",dice2)

        score=dice1+dice2
        if score%2==0:
            score=score+10
        else:
            score=score-5

        if dice1==dice2:
            print("You rolled a double- You get an extra roll")
            for x in range (1):
                print("You rolled a:")
                extraDice=(random.randint(1,6))
                print(extraDice)
                extraScore = score+extraDice
                score = extraScore



        print("======","Your combined score is ", score,"======")

        # Store result of this round for player 1
        if score != 0:
            result_p1[count] = score
        else:
            result_p1[count] = 0

        score=0
        print("Player Two rolls first dice")
        time.sleep(1)
        dice1=(random.randint(1,6))
        print("you rolled a ",dice1)
        print("Player Two rolls second dice")
        time.sleep(1)
        dice2=(random.randint(1,6))
        print("you rolled a ",dice2)

        score=dice1+dice2
        if score%2==0:
            score=score+10
        else:
            score=score-5
        if dice1==dice2:
            print("You rolled a double- You get an extra roll")
            for x in range (1):
                print("You rolled a:")
                extraDice=(random.randint(1,6))
                print(extraDice)
                extraScore = score+extraDice
                score = extraScore

        print("======","Your combined score is ", score,"======")

        # Store result of this round for player 2
        if score != 0:
            result_p2[count] = score
        else:
            result_p2[count] = 0

    # Print sum of results using f-string in python 3.
    print(f"Player 1 scores: {result_p1}")
    print(f"Player 2 scores: {result_p2}")
    print(f"Sum of player 1 score: {sum(result_p1.values())}")
    print(f"Sum of player 2 score: {sum(result_p2.values())}")

def main():
   bothDice()


main()
```

[This](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) might be useful if my print statement didn't make sense.

Here is an output of the new print statements.

```
Player 1 scores: {1: 9, 2: 13, 3: 17, 4: 0, 5: 19}
Player 2 scores: {1: 17, 2: 13, 3: 13, 4: -2, 5: -2}
Sum of player 1 score: 58
Sum of player 2 score: 39
```

Edit: Added `if` statements before adding score to player `dict` to check if `score` is negative. If negative -> add `0` instead.

Comment: if a player scores an even number its supposed to add 10 points- it doesnt do this. also how would you make sure the points dont go below 0

Comment: `Round 1
Player One rolls first dice
you rolled a  2
Player One rolls second dice
you rolled a  2
You rolled a double- You get an extra roll
You rolled a:
2
====== Your combined score is  16 ======` This was one of my runs. It seems to be doing it just fine. For your second question. It depends on what you're looking for. What's the logic if you do get a `negative` score?

Comment: the scores are not supposed to go below 0

Comment: when i ran the code i got this:   Player Two rolls first dice
you rolled a  2
Player Two rolls second dice
you rolled a  4
====== Your combined score is  11 ======                                                          i think it only works for doubles

Comment: Right it makes sense not to have scores go negative. But if the score IS negative, are you looking to basically turn it into 0? Or does the player get to go again somehow?

Comment: That's because the rules you created. You said that "If `dice1` and `dice2` are equal, give the player an extra roll OTHERWISE subtract 5 points from the score. Unless this is not what you wanted, the logic is wrong in your code. So `dice1 = 2`, `dice2 = 4` -- even number therefore `+ 10` -- `score = 16` but since `dice1 != dice2` SUBTRACT 5 which gives you `11` score for the round. These are rules you wrote for your game.

Comment: the score turns into 0

Comment: an even number gets 10 points   odd gets -5 points     double gets extra go

Comment: Your code is incorrect then since the `else` statement for subtracting 5 is all the way down there instead of being right after checking for `even` numbers.

Comment: @hussainahmed Check edit now. I have added the changes you requested.

Comment: I don't see why you need `elif` for those conditions. I have a feeling that you mis-wrote the rules of the game because some of the things you mentioned don't match with the code you wrote. Please take some time and edit your question to exactly what you're looking for and this attempt.

Comment: how would i make sure that if both players have the same score at the end, they each roll 1 die and whoever gets the highest score wins (this repeats until someone wins). after that how would show who has won at the end and store the winner’s score in a txt file and display the score from the txt file. thanks

Comment: I'd suggest that you take some time and go over a `python` tutorial.